# Really frustrating debug Error with C++

Tags: c++

So I am trying to make a pretty basic TicTacToe in C++, and while I have no apparent syntax errors, I am having a lot of Debug errors of : "Unhandled exception at 0x0100142D in Cobra.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCC359"

I feel like it is an obvious Error that I am just not processing but it;s definitely starting to grate my nerves. I'll label where the access error is... Right now it;s in my checkwin method but I feel like there is definitely more than one..

In my header I use a private char** board and a private int player.

```
#include "TicTacToe.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int rowChosen,
        colChosen;

    TicTacToe newGame;

    while(newGame.checkWin()==' ' && !newGame.fullBoard())
    {
        newGame.displayBoard();
        do
        {
            cout << "Player " << newGame.getPlayer() << " choose a row and column.";
            cin >> rowChosen >> colChosen;

            newGame.setGame(rowChosen,colChosen);

        }while(newGame.setGame(rowChosen,colChosen)==false);

        newGame.makeMove(rowChosen, colChosen, newGame.getPlayer());
        newGame.switchPlayer();
    }

    newGame.displayBoard();
    if(newGame.checkWin()!=' ')
        cout << "Player " << newGame.returnWinner() << " wins!";
    else if(newGame.fullBoard()==true)
        cout << "Cat's Game: This is a Draw!";

    return 0;
}

TicTacToe::TicTacToe()
{
    player = 1;

    char blank = ' ';                       
    for(int row=0;row<3;row++)              
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++)
            board[row][col] = ' ';
}

void TicTacToe::setPlayer(int play)
{
    player = play;
}


int TicTacToe::getPlayer()
{
    return player;
}

void TicTacToe::switchPlayer()
{
    if (player==1)
        player++;
    else
        player--;
}

bool TicTacToe::setGame(int row, int col)       //input validation
{
    if (row >= 3 || row < 0) 
        return false;
    if (col >= 3 || col < 0) 
        return false; 
    if (board[row][col] != ' ')
        return false;

    return true;
}

char TicTacToe::getBoard(int row, int col)
{
    return board[row][col];
}

bool TicTacToe::fullBoard()
{
    bool full = true;

    for(int row=0;row<3;row++)  
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++)
        {
            if(board[row][col]==' ')
            {
                full=false;
                break;
            }       
        }
    return full;    
}

void TicTacToe::makeMove(int r, int c, int player)
{
    char ch;
    if (player==1)
        ch = 'X';
    else
        ch = 'O';
    board[r][c] = ch;
}

char TicTacToe::checkWin()
{
    char b = ' ';
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) //horizontal
    {
        if((board[i][1]==board[i][0]) && (board[i][1]==board[i][2])) //THIS IS ERROR
        {
            b=board[i][1];
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++) //vertical
    {
        if( (board[1][j]==board[0][j]) && (board[1][j]==board[2][j]) ) 
            b=board[1][j];
    }
    if((board[0][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[2][2]) ||
       (board[2][0]==board[1][1] && board[1][1]==board[0][2]))
        b= board[1][1];
    return b;   
}

void TicTacToe::displayBoard()
{
    for(int row=0;row<3;row++)
    {
        cout << "|-----|";
        for(int col=0;col<3;col++)
        {
            if(board[row][col]==' ')
                cout << "| ";
            else
                cout << "|" << board [row][col];
        }
        cout << "|" << endl;
        cout << "|-----|";

    }
}

int TicTacToe::returnWinner()
{
    int winner = 0;
    if(checkWin()=='X')
        winner = 1;
    else if(checkWin()=='O')
        winner = 2;
    return winner;
}
```

This is my header TicTacToe.h

```
class TicTacToe
{
 private:
    char board[3][3];     //there we go
    int player;

 public:
    TicTacToe();
    void setPlayer(int);
    int getPlayer();
    void switchPlayer();
    bool setGame(int,int);
char getBoard(int,int);
    bool fullBoard();
    void makeMove(int,int,int);
    char checkWin();
    void displayBoard();
    int returnWinner();
};
```

Comment: `TicTacToe::TicTacToe() { char board[3][3];` is almost certainly a bug, why do you want a local called `board` inside your constructor? Please indent your code properly, and show the class declaration once you've narrowed down the problem - probably 80+% of the code you posted is irrelevant.

Comment: Include the class declaration for `TicTacToe`. And "In my header I use a private `char**`..." - is almost certainly your first mistake, as there is nothing in your constructor the allocates the requisite memory for that construct (which you shouldn't be using anyway, since you already know it is a 3x3 board). You initialize a local automatic variable `board` in the constructor which effectively does *nothing*, as it is lost as soon as the constructor finishes.

Comment: I see it, the first time I took a swing at it I had made the board in the constructor and made a call function for whatever reason and when I changed it I didnt remove that snippet. I'm now recieving errors in the constructor itself when I am trying to fill it with empty ' ' chars...

Comment: So include the actual .h file and let us see the code.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone, It did turn out to be an easy fix, now it's just the small display/logic errors which are easy to deal with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've included all the code, you're missing something essential: the declaration of the class TicTacToe. Of course, there's a `TicTacToe.h`, so it could be (probably is) hiding in there. That would help.

That all said, I think Mat has it right -- you declare a local named `board` inside the ctor and initialize it. But that goes out of scope as soon as the ctor is finished, which means all that initialization disappears into the aether.. Assuming you define `board` in your class, then simply removing that `char` declaration might be all you need.

Now, here's general advice: if you get an access violation exception, it usually means that you have made a mistake about the scope of something you're referring to.  Since the exception happens at a point where you're using `board`, the *[slice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing)* of the program containing the identified `board` is the place to look.

Comment: You're right, I see the problem though. I thought I was allocating the space for board in the constructor but I was just making a new board in which case the private board is still just an empty space without even the empty array space itself

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make, especially when you don't distinguish member variables from local variables. A common practice is to prefix member variables with "m_", e.g. "m_board".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It's still hard to make those adjustments between java and C++ when my college uses so much java and not much C++, I think dynamic allocation was simply frustrating coming from Java so I didnt really get how to use it